# How does affected_rows() Work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function create($tableName, $userInput) {

    $this->db->insert($tableName, $userInput);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();

}
```

As you see, `$this->db->affected_rows();` is not referencing to any specific resource/executed statement.

**Does affected_rows() return latest affected_rows() in the database generally? In other words, if i have 50 users calling create(...) function, how does codeigniter associate each affected_rows() to its executed statement?**

This questions is codeigniter specific.

Comment: You would have to delve into the code to be 100% sure, but it would return the last affected_rows() under the specific connection held by the `db` resource handle.

Comment: when you connect to a database you get a `handle` and this magical handle is a 'unique' identifier for each connection, `affected_rows()` gets the number of the affected rows by the last transaction using this connection .
Update: @Joe, so close!

Comment: @Adnan code igniter does a hack to their affected_rows() helper though for mysql, but I figured it worked like that.  It's tied to the resource handle.

Comment: @Joe, I meant "so close!" for the timing of our comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter `system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php` at line 337:

```
/**
 * Affected Rows
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  integer
 */
function affected_rows()
{
    return @mysql_affected_rows($this->conn_id);
}
```

Which basically means there are no difference between CodeIgniter and standard PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

It returns the number of rows which were affected by the last query, so if you have problems and it's always returning 1, it means codeigniter iterates your query, a quick workaround for this to work is to use your own query with `$this->db->query();'

Comment: "It returns the number of rows which were affected by the last query" Last query of a particular connection? I could have different users running 30 queries at a single time...

Comment: You can read more about "Atomic functions", "Transactions". But to answer your question, it uses the last query in this current connection. If you use database library in codeigniter with only one connection (usually you should, unless you want to connect to different databases) and thus it will return the current instance's (read "user's") last action rows. I should note, though, if you are using AJAX, it will create a new connection and not use the same used in the main application.